# Squid won't start in Arch Linux

Tags: squid

I just installed Squid in my machine running Arch Linux. When I try to start it, it gives me this message :

> bash: /usr/sbin/squid: cannot execute binary file

How can I fix this?

Comment: How did you install it?   Did you compile from source or use a package appropriate for your system?

Comment: @Zoredache I just used pacman to install it from the repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that you mixed up some repos?
Maybe you have a 32 bit Arch and installed the 64 bit Squid package?

Comment: Nope... I have ARM and installed the ARM package

Comment: Pleas post the output of: `uname -a` and `file /usr/sbin/squid`

Comment: uname -a : Linux plug-server 3.1.10-4-ARCH #1 PREEMPT Wed Feb 29 04:02:24 UTC 2012 armv5tel Feroceon 88FR131 rev 1 (v5l) Marvell SheevaPlug Reference Board GNU/Linux

Comment: file /usr/sbin/squid  :  /usr/sbin/squid: data

Comment: Whoops, `file /usr/sbin/squid` doesn't show what I expect. Hm, don't have access to a linux box by now, can't remember exact command out of my head. Anyway, I see three possibilities here: 1. Package was compiled with wrong architecture 2. You are using the wrong package for your architecture or 3. What are your mount options? Is /usr mounted with `noexec` switch?

Comment: Hmmm my friend, how to check the architecture of the package? My /etc/fstab shows this :            #
# /etc/fstab: static file system information
#
# <file system> <dir>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
tmpfs           /tmp    tmpfs   nodev,nosuid    0       0

Comment: You can check it with `file`. That's what I tried with `file /usr/sbin/squid` but it don't work this way. Maybe if you look in the pacman cache? Something like `file /var/cache/pacman/squid.x.y.z.tar.gz`...

Comment: Here's the result : squid-3.1.19-1-arm.pkg.tar.xz: XZ compressed data

Comment: Mhhh, no. It has to be something like: `/usr/sbin/squid: ELF armv5tel executable foo bar` but I don't know why it doesn't show such an output if you run `file /usr/sbin/squid`....sorry

Comment: Anyway.. thanks for the help! Can you please tell me what flags to use when compiling squid from source? I need SSL bump and ICAP support!

Answer (score 1):

If possible, I would

```
pacman -Rs squid
pacman -Syu squid

rc.d start squid
```

and carefully check the logs for both pacman and squid.

Comment: Did it... The pacman log is fine except for :  [2012-03-09 08:54] warning: /etc/squid/squid.conf saved as /etc/squid/squid.conf.pacsave           I removed it before re installing Squid. The squid logs are empty (The Squid folder in /var/logs is empty!)

Comment: Try to change mirror editing /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist uncommenting all but the one line for the mirror you choose and repeat the above steps.

Comment: Tried two mirrors... Cleared pacman cache and tried to re install twice... Still the problem is there!